# How to replace "i" in <li>anything</li> using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to replace "i" in `<li>anything</li>` using regex

Code :

```
var code = "<li>anything</li>"; // i don't know what is in <li>......</li>
```

result should be :

```
var code = "<li>anyth1ng</li>"; // i don't know what is in <li>......</li>
```

Comment: Is this an *element* you have, or a *string* you have?

Comment: Also, consider creating the actual element via jQuery and then fetching its text contents: `$(code).text()` That way you can be sure that the HTML tags are not destroyed accidentally...

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the information you gave us, these should work:

```
code = code.replace(/hi/g, "he");
code = code.replace(/i\</g, "e<");
```

If you have more requirements, please update the question to describe them.

**Updated**

```
var code = "<li>hi ho hi ho it's off to work we go</li>";
code = code.replace(/\>.*\</g, function(m) {
   return m.replace(/i/g, "e");
});
```

Comment: <li>anything</li> to <li>anyth!ng</li>

Comment: The modification I just made will replace any "i" between the opening ">" and the closing "<". Will that work?

Comment: What do you mean by "more professional"?   You could do it in one line.  (Why do you count 4?  I count 3 for the actual solution.)

Comment: @faressoft Do you think jQuery with code being in 1 line is professional? Man I would be afraid to read your code with no line breaks.